# Drools unable to upload jar file

Tags: jar, model, drools, uploading, guvnor

Recently I was trying to upload a new jar file for our Model with Drools, but errors happened and it simply didn't work. The error message was "Unable to upload the file." I tried all the ways to build the jar files including use maven,  terminal command line jar command, as well as update the old working jar file with "jar uf" command. So the difference of the old working jar file and the new jar file is that I added two new model class, nothing special, but it simply didn't now allow me to upload the new version jar file.

I tried to google solutions but no luck since almost no people discuss this problem. All the documents I can find just mention simple POJO model class jar should be fine. Is there any special we need to pay attention for the POJO jar file? Like the JDK version? Dependencies in jar file? but I also tried using jdk 1.6 instead of 1.8, and also tried building a jar from java class directly using terminal command without any dependencies, and still not working while uploading.

Another error is "Unable to validate package configuration (eg, DSLs, models) for 'xxxxxxx'. Suggestion completions may not operate correctly for graphical editors for this package." when I clicked the open button.

Any suggestions? I really appreciate that if anybody can give any possible solution.

Comment: Without a stacktrace and the version of Drools you are using, it would be very difficult to get some help. The most obvious reason I can think about is that your jar now depends on a jar that is no present in guvnor/workbench. But as far as I understand, your jar doesn't depend on any other. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks Esteban! Yes, they are all POJOs without any new dependencies compared with the previous Jar which are working. It's really weird as I tried all the ways I can think to build a Jar file. Btw, do you know how to check the stacktrace of the server since I can't find where to see the stacktrace in the Drools UI?

Comment: You will need to check the logs on your server (i.e. Tomcat or Wildfly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that only jar files below jdk 1.7 are working for it. Also we need get rid of all dependencies.